# Register a dll that references multiple dlls

Tags: c#, com, reference, regasm

Ok I have 2 questions and I'm in a pickle here and have been for a week.

**Important** - No application will build this or run it.  It will be a single client side dll (that references several other dll's) that will be placed in specific folder and I will need to register this dll using regasm or something.

**OverView:**

So I have a c# COM ScannerController.dll written.  ScannerController references five 3rd party dll's that will already be installed and registered in folders throughout c:\Program Features\etc.... (the locations will change depending on the version of the software that they are on, but the dll will be the same.)

This one dll (integration.ActiveX (it's an assembly)) has a method called InstalledPath.   InstalledPath returns the actual location of the executing assembly.  When I finished the dll I ran it through IExplorer and it was returning the correct "../program features/....".

Then, in order to set it up on another computer I unregistered it and then ran some regasms and registered the dll at "Scanner/bin/debug/integration.ActiveX" (which oleview says it can't find it's dependencies) So I unregistered it, built it in vs2012 and now when I run it from IExplorer, the InstalledPath is "../bin/debug/".  I created a new projecte, built it which auto registered it, and ran it from iexplorer and the InstalledPath is "..Scanner-fake/bin/debug/".  I've unregistered it a million times in cmd and no matter what I do, it is now always pointing at the debug folder of the registered ScannerController.

**Question 1:**

How in the world do i register my COM ScannerController.dll, using something like regasm, and also point it to the five 3rd party dlls that ScannerController references?

**Question 2:**

I tried fixing it to where Integration.dll wouldn't exists in the local path on my computer (since i'm building it) so I set the copy local to false.  When I build it, view it in oleview, it says that its dependencies cannot be loaded or found.  How can I set the project up so that, with the copy local = false, the references can find the other 3rd party dlls?

Sorry for the lengthy question but thank you so much for reading and attempting to help me out.  I have searched high and low for this and I am just mentally exhausted now.

Comment: Integration.Activex.dll, ScannerController.dll (built in VS2012) plus 5 3rd party (com?) dlls already installed and registered on target computers. Is this what you have?

Comment: Sorry, the Integration.ActiveX.dll is one of the 3rd party dll's (which all 3rd party dll's have been registered on my machine).  4 of the 3rd party dlls are Type:Assembly and 1 is Type: ActiveX. And yes ScannerControll.dll is a COM object and it is built locally on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

**1) ScannerController.dll**

COM registration using `regasm ScannerController.dll`

**2) 3rd Party ActiveX dll**

Assuming it's already registered: No action required. (Otherwise register with `regsvr32`)

**3) 3rd Party Managed Libraries** (no com types/libsexposed)

Use one of the following 2 option to guarantie that your ScannerController Libraray can access these managed libraries:

- Copy them to the folder where your ScannerController.dll  or maybe (I am not 100% sure, you have to test it) to the folder where the ScannerController.dll host - the exe / the process calling  ScannerController.dll - resides
- Register these libs in the [global assembly cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache) (the registry pendant for managed libraries) to make them globally available to other applications

Comment: I can't put them in the same path sadly.  The only way for versioning for this one company is to look at the file path (which I think is stupid).Is there anyway, for the 3rd party managed libraries, that I can set the class ID?  I know each library's class id.  Or is there any way I can set a directory for it to look.  This one company will have ../program Files/Inuvio/ics 5.5.  Then their new software is ../Inuvio/ics 6.0.  Can I set it to look for the dll at the ../Inuvio directory?  And all of your examples are referring to it as copy local = false right?

Comment: What do you mean with you know the class Id. The ClassId (Guid) from registry? I thought it's pure managed code. Managed code is not regisered unless it exposes com interfaces.

Comment: Yes I know the GUID from the registry.  I'm not quite sure what you mean by managed code (was going to look into definition so I did not sound stupid, but my brain is fried! lol.), but yes the com objects are exposed and I know all of the 3rd party dll GUIDS.

Comment: So they are com components and fall in the same category as the activeX dll. interfaces and type are resolved through registry. There is no nee to know where they resist. Just put your own dll in a folder register it using regasm. What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: I am assuming because I am referencing a dll, when I go to Regasm my dll on another machine it says that it was successful BUT, when I look in oleView at my registry, it says that it's dependencies cannot be found.  Which in turn makes it essentially not exists and can't be called from my class.